# vertical align with picture and text

Tags: html, css

I am having some problems with making a picture and text align vertical correct on a mobile. It is this page:

[See the example page](http://mimsi.dk/my-account/)

On a mobile I would like the picture is going out to the pink lines I made:

[image: Mobile View]

In the inspector window I have tried to set the padding and margin to 0px. But that is not working. Does anybody have an idea how to solve this problem?

The CSS for the image should be this one:

**Correction: I can actually see that the CSS counts all the images**

```
element.style {
}
style.min.css?ver=4.9:1
.w-image-h, .w-image a, .w-image img {
    border-radius: inherit;
    border-color: inherit !important;
    color: inherit !important;
}
style.min.css?ver=4.9:1
img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
style.min.css?ver=4.9:1
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
img[Attributes Style] {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Is it something with media queries?

Comment: What is the CSS of the image?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I just updated my question.

Comment: Do not post a link to your site. That may change in the future. Post the relevant HTML in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On mobile, update the width of the image. Add a class to tag `<img class="cls">` then add width to that class. Your image will comply.